# What does "you are one off us" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

After Chelsea's defeat in the last round of the PL by Liverpool, there appeared a banner in the Chelsea fan section with this text:

> **Jose, you are one off us**.

Is it some kind of a wordplay based on similarity *of/off*? An ironic teasing that wants to say that the manager of Chelsea should be removed?

Comment: ...Or it could just be a mistake made by a non-native speaker.  Especially considering that the common expression is "one of us", not "***the*** one of us".

Comment: It seems to me that you got it right. Jose was considered one of "them" before. But after so many defeats, he is not one of them. This is my guess.

Comment: I am not sure if there was the definite article before "one". BTW: what's wrong with "you are the one"?

Comment: The article would make sense if it was "one-off", meaning "Happening, done, or made only once". The phrase "the one-off us" doesn't make sense to me though. It could be "Jose, you are the one (that is) off (of) us." but that doesn't make sense either.

Comment: @VictorBazarov - Or it could just be a mistake made by a **native** speaker! Not everyone born in the UK learnt how to spell.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that this is a play on "one-off", which means unique. So you get a message of acceptance/inclusion:

> You are one of us

And an homage to his talent:

> You are a one-off

Note that I don't even know which sport Chelsea plays, so I could be seriously wrong through lack of context.

Comment: Chelsea are performing poorly in the PL. As I have stated earlier in my comment: *Jose was considered one of "them" before. But after so many defeats, he is not one of them* It was not "one-off" or "a mistake," rather it was clever of the fan to say "you are one **off** us"